# Access functions/properties from another class

Tags: c#, dll

I've got a bunch of classes within an external library, that is not part of my application I'm working on.

Since my application uses it's own library, that also contains numerous functions, I want to use the classes/objects from the external library aswell.

Let's say, I've got a class like this in my external dll:

```
namespace Mydll.ExternalDLL
{
    public class ObjectClass
    {
        public void DoSomething() { }
    }
}
```

Since I don't want to reference the external dll to my application, I need to access this function from somewhere else.

So, the idea was to do something like this within my internal, referenced dll:

```
using Mydll.ExternalDLL;
namespace Mydll.InternalDLL
{
    public class ObjectClass : Mydll.ExternalDLL.ObjectClass
    {
        public void DoSomethingElse() { }
    }
}
```

As you can see there's no function called DoSomething() inside my internal dll.
When calling ObjectClass from the internal dll, I simply want to have access to DoSomething() AND DoSomethingElse() at the same time without some strange conversion which will lead to reference both library to my application.
The internal dll will be more like a extension-package complementing missing functions from its base.

Is there any way to achieve what I want or am I simply blind to some restrictions I am missing?

Comment: Why can't you add a reference to your library?

Comment: Well, I could. But I don't want to, because every relating function/object should be processed only by accessing the internal dll. I forgot to mention that the external dll was written by another company and I do not own the source code.

So anyone using that library only have to add the internal one, having access to anything both libraries contains. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid referencing external dll. Either explicitly, or implicitly, but you've got to do that.
You can create your own wrappers, if that is what you need. It helps to gain a bit more of control over your dependencies.

```
using Mydll.ExternalDLL;
public class ObjectClassWrapper
{
    ObjectClass _objectClass = new ObjectClass();
    public void DoSomething() 
    { 
       _objectClass.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, had that in mind as the final solution. But this will result in weeks of writing "unneeded" code to just wrap around the external library. The external library will be referenced to the internal dll. - EDIT: just corrected some parts of the code in my entry post. That would be more clear to what I want, I hope.